# error: The argument type '(File) → Future<dynamic>' can't be assigned to the parameter type '(dynamic) → FutureOr<dynamic>'

Tags: dart, flutter, future

I'm trying to compile the example from:
https://github.com/dart-lang/googleapis_examples/blob/master/drive_upload_download_console/bin/main.dart

### and I get the following Dart compile error

> error: The argument type '(File) → Future'  can't be assigned
>   to the parameter type '(dynamic) → FutureOr'.
>   (argument_type_not_assignable at lib/google_api_rest/main.dart:49)

from following code:

```
 // Download a file from Google Drive.
    Future downloadFile(drive.DriveApi api,
                        Client client,
                        String objectId,
                        String filename) {
      return api.files.get(objectId).then((drive.File file) {
        // The Drive API allows one to download files via `File.downloadUrl`.
        return client.readBytes(file.downloadUrl).then((bytes) {
          var stream = new File(filename).openWrite()..add(bytes);
          return stream.close();
        });
      });
```

I use Android Studio 3.2.1, Dart-Idk 2.1.0-dev.9.4 with Flutter 1.0.0 stable-channel.

***I new to Dart and Flutter,
can someone help me to resolve this issue ?***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`api.files.get()` is statically declared to [return a `Future`](https://pub.dartlang.org/documentation/googleapis/latest/googleapis.drive.v3/FilesResourceApi/get.html). A bare `Future` with no generic is implicitly a `Future<dynamic>`. The [`Future<T>.then`](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.1.0/dart-async/Future/then.html) call takes a `Function(T)`, which means `Function(dynamic)`. You're passing a `Function(File)`.

You might know that the `Future` will always resolve to a `File`, but statically the compiler doesn't know that.

Ideally the signature of of `api.files.get()` should be updated to indicate it returns a `Future<File>`. In the mean time you can work around this:

```
  return api.files.get(objectId).then((result) {
    var file = result as drive.File;
    // The Drive API allows one to download files via `File.downloadUrl`.
    return client.readBytes(file.downloadUrl).then((bytes) {
      var stream = new File(filename).openWrite()..add(bytes);
      return stream.close();
    });
```